# I edited a file with the command "sudo xed /etc/fstab" and now my computer boots to the command line, how can I go back to GUI?

Tags: boot, readonly

I was watching a video about what to do after installing Linux mint and the guy in the video said that you should run the command `sudo xed /etc/fstab` and substitute `errors=remount-ro` with `errors=remount-ro.noatime`.

I did that, but after I rebooted the system it went to a command line, and since then I can't go back to the GUI. Apparently this file that I edited has something to do with read only mode. I can't edit files, what implies that I can't undo the edit.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `sudo xed /etc/fstab` is bad advice, in any case should be `sudo -H xed /etc/fstab`.

Comment: Boot from a live linux usb and try to edit the file there.

Comment: Hello :-). I've already tried this, it says "Error writing /etc/fstab: Read-only file system".

Comment: I dont have a pendrive but I will try to get one. Thanks for your time.

Comment: When you boot from a rescue environment, `/etc/fstab` is the one belonging to that environment. You need to use the rescue system to edit the one on your disk, and change `errors=remount-ro.noatime` to `errors=remount-ro,noatime` (the dot should be a comma)

Comment: I dont know if I understood ... How do I use the rescue system?

Comment: @Gabrielᴛʀᴀᴠᴀᴢᴀᴘ Once you boot a live linux usb, the `/etc/fstab` is the one belonging to the live system. To edit the *disk* file, you need to mount it first, then follow the path of the mounted disk, example `/media/usr/YOUR_DISK/etc/fstab`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to run the command `mount -o remount,rw /dev/sda1` as a root user.